# Modifiers denoting colour, provenance, and composition in a fused-head noun phrases

Tags: determiners, modifiers, noun-phrases, fused-head-constructions

In section **9.3 Fusion of internal modifier and head**, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 417) says:

> **(d) Modifiers denoting colour, provenance, and composition** 
> [25] i Henrietta likes red shirts, and I like [*blue*].
>
> ii Knut wanted the purple wallpaper, but I wanted [the *mauve*].
>
> iii Henrietta likes Russian vodka, and I like [*Polish*].
>
> iv Knut wanted the French caterers, but I wanted [the *Italian*].
>
> v I prefer cotton shirts to [*nylon*].
>
> vi Knut likes malt whisky, but I prefer [*blended*].
>
> The NPs here are either bare or have a definite determiner; there is significant loss of acceptability when the determiner is indefinite: 
> [26] i <sup>?</sup>Harvey bought a red *shirt* and I bought [a *blue*]. 
>  ii <sup>?</sup>I bought some Chinese *food* rather than [some *Indian*]. 
> iii <sup>?</sup>I bought a cotton *shirt* rather than [a *nylon*].

In [26], does the acceptability increase if the determiner is removed as in [26']?

> [26'] i Harvey bought a red *shirt* and I bought [*blue*]. 
>  ii I bought some Chinese *food* rather than [*Indian*]. 
> iii I bought a cotton *shirt* rather than [*nylon*].

Here are some attested examples that might suggest [26'] i-iii do work.

> For those who prefer their international cricket played with *a red ball* rather than *white*, the past six weeks have required a great deal of patience.
>
> ([The Guardian, Aug 2022](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2022/aug/16/england-aim-to-reignite-early-summer-spark-but-will-be-wary-of-south-africa))

> Unlike the previous version, the new Messages and Contacts app icons do not use shadows and feature *a white background* rather than *blue*.
>
> ([Android Police, Oct 2022](https://www.androidpolice.com/new-google-messages-contacts-app-icons-rolling-out-beta/))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140085/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-modifiers-denoting-colour-provenance-and-composi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's more acceptable without the determiner.

If you use a determiner, you can sometimes append a pronoun to make it acceptable:

> 26i. Harvey bought a red shirt and I bought a blue one.
> 26iii. I bought a cotton shirt rather than a nylon one.

However, I don't think this works for mass nouns like "food" -- I can't think of a pronoun that can be put after "Indian" in 26ii.